# When should I use abstraction in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my past I've seen some Java EE, .Net and other enterprise application architectures. Each of those had at least one abstract upper class used to generalize for example the service layer: AbstractService

But when it comes to Angular I've never seen something like this. Even if it has some standardized service/api layer.

I wonder if it might be considered bad practice in typescript since it's just JavaScript underneath. Or is it just that there are no tutorials or guidelines going that deep and real world enterprise apps would indeed use that abstraction? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: First abstract classes are from Java SE not EE.

Comment: About Java EE tool like `spring` have some cool better inventions then abstract classes like `Dependency Injection`.

Comment: Im working with Angular for 2 years, used it maybe twice and it was also specific for a case I develpoed something that I could do without it. Angular itself didn't requiered any use of absract classes in my day job.

Comment: Angular, Unlike Java and .Net is not a language,
the language is Javascript here...  inheritance can be implemented with TypeScript;

Comment: I have implemented enterprise level angular using base TypeScript classes for angular services and components

Comment: *have his own Dependency Injection tools and he call them services* no, it calls it dependency injection.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yeha you right that was stupid deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few common use cases for `abstract` classes in Angular, the most prominent being *abstract* classes used as *dependency injection tokens*

**Dependency Injection Token (implements)**

```
export abstract class AbstractEventService {
  dispatchEvent(event: any): void;
  listen(event: any): Observable<any>;
}

// Use the abstract class as interfaces
export class EventService implements AbstractEventService {
   // The compiler will force you to implement dispatchEvent() and listen()
}
```

```
// use the abstract class as a DI token (which you cannot do with interfaces)
providers: [provide: AbstractEventService , useClass: EventService ]
```

This approach is very useful for unit testing. You can override in `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` or `TestBed.overrideProvider()`

**Service Base Classes (extends)**

I haven't seen this used as much in tutorials or demos, but it's used in real-world apps

```
export abstract class AbstractBaseService {
   // extending classes forced to implement these properties/functions
   protected abstract serviceID: string;
   protected abstract provideInitialState(): IState;

   protected formatResponse(response: IAccountResponse): IFormattedResponse {
       // logic accessible to sub-classes
       // override if necessary
   }
}

export class AccountService extends AbstractBaseService {
   // implement abstract properties and functions
   // override protected/private properties and functions if needs be
}
```

**Notes**

You'll notice that I mention overriding protected/private properties and functions - this is a limitation of TypeScript, as it allows overriding of any Abstract class properties and functions

Comment: I agree about your comment with the lack of tutorials and demos using extended base classes. Particularly for services. You can cut down on a lot of CRUD overhead with a base service and can wrapper the standard http requests so that you can easily handle request errors in a manner specific to your app in one location rather than writing the same "on error" code over and over in separate services.

Comment: @Rob that's more what I was thinking about when writing the post. Nice to hear that some people do that with crud services!